# Dumping public key from private using libopenssl

Tags: c++, openssl, rsa, private-key, public-key

Let say I want to have a code doing something like this openssl command in my c++ application.

```
openssl rsa -in private.pem -pubout -outform der -out ./out.pub
```

How can I do that?

I was look for a sample on github and came up with follow scheme.

```
key  = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(bio, NULL, 0, NULL);
len = i2d_RSAPublicKey(key, &bufp);
```

It returns different value than I'm getting from command line tool. I suppose there was no conversion from private key to public and it just saves the private key. Could any one tell me the right approach for getting pub key from private using openssl lib. I would also greatly appreciate any links to pub\priv key examples for openssl.

Comment: Maybe there is a program somewhere where you can look at the source code that can do this conversion...

Answer (score 2):

Finally I've just find proper sources inside openssl itself. Here is exactly what happens during

> openssl rsa -in private.pem -pubout -outform der -out ./out.pub

I've dropped lots of checks from original code to make it smaller.

```
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>

EVP_PKEY *load_key(const char *file)
{
    BIO *key=NULL;
    EVP_PKEY *pkey=NULL;

    key=BIO_new(BIO_s_file());
    BIO_read_filename(key,file);
    pkey=PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(key,NULL,NULL,NULL);

    return pkey;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    BIO *out=NULL;
    out=BIO_new(BIO_s_file());
    EVP_PKEY    *pkey;
    RSA *rsa=NULL;

    char *infile = path_to_pem;
    char *outfile = path_to_der;

    pkey = load_key(infile);

    if (pkey != NULL)
        rsa = EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(pkey);
    EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);

    BIO_write_filename(out,outfile);

    i2d_RSA_PUBKEY_bio(out,rsa);
}
```